# Определение максимальной суммы элементов при минимальной разнице сумм максимальных и минимальных подсписков

Tags: python, алгоритм

нужно выбрать подсписки при которых разница между
суммой максимальных и минимальных будет минимальна

например для такой пары подойдут оба:

```
[
[1, 3, 0],
[2, 1, 4]
]
```

max(1 + 2, 3 + 1, 0 + 4)−min(1 + 2, 3 + 1, 0 + 4) = 1

если бы мы взяли только одну, то вышло
max(1, 3, 0)−min(1, 3, 0) = 3, что не является минимальным, а значит не подходит

В данном примере

```
[
[0, 0, 5],
[0, 4, 0],
[0, 8, 0],
[2, 1, 0],
[3, 0, 0]
]
```

мы берем 1, 2, 4, 5 строки

max(0+0+2+3, 0+4+1+0, 5+0+0+0) − min(0+0+2+3, 0+4+1+0, 5+0+0+0) == 0 - является минимальным числом

в случае если есть несколько таких ситуаций, то нужно выбрать где сумма всех элементов будет больше

Конечно, условие возможно будет немного непонятным, но я попытался максимально расписать.

Comment: и вы намекаете, что есть алгоритм, который найдёт это быстрее чем полный перебор всех наборов подсписков?

Comment: @ESkri, без полного перебора не получится.

Comment: Почему не указаны ограничения на величины в задаче?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Теория

Задача решается полным перебором всех комбинаций. Быстрее нельзя, и вот почему:

Заменим задачу на более простую: для данного набора списков требуется ответить есть ли комбинация с нулевой разницей или её нет. Ясно что если вы умеете решать общую задачу (про поиск минимальной разницы), то и эту решите без труда.

Рассмотрим списки из двух элементов. Например:

> ```
> [0, 5]
> [4, 0]
> [8, 0]
> [1, 0]
> ```

Заметим что если ко всем элементам конкретного списка прибавить одно и то же число, ответ останется прежним. Добавим к каждому списку такое число, чтобы первый элемент стал нулем:

> ```
> [0,  5]
> [0, -4]
> [0, -8]
> [0, -1]
> ```

Комбинация с нулевой разницей тогда возможна только если есть комбинация вторых чисел списков, которая даёт нулевую сумму. Можно среди этих чисел отыскать  непустую комбинацию с нулевой суммой?

> ```
> 5, -4, -8, -1
> ```

Это [задача о сумме подмножеств](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2):

> Задача заключается в нахождении (хотя бы одного) непустого
> подмножества некоторого набора чисел, чтобы сумма чисел этого
> подмножества равнялась нулю.

Она [NP-полная](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0). То есть, она решается только полным перебором вариантов.

Раскручиваем цепочку назад. Если бы для исходной задачи существовало бы быстрое решение, то и задача проверки нулевой разницы для списков из двух элементов решалась бы быстро. Тогда и задача о сумме подмножеств решалась бы быстро. А это, скорее всего, невозможно - NP-полнота.

Ещё раз, коротко: задача может быть решена только полным перебором всех комбинаций.

### Практика

Перебор написать не сложно:

```
def cost(s):
    return max(s) - min(s), -sum(s)


def search(a):
    m = len(a)
    n = len(a[0])
    s = [0] * n

    best_s = a[0]
    best_c = cost(a[0])
    
    def rec(i, empty):
        nonlocal best_s
        nonlocal best_c
        if i == m:
            if not empty:
                c = cost(s)
                if c < best_c:
                    best_s = s[:]
                    best_c = c
        else:
            rec(i + 1, empty)
            for j in range(n):
                s[j] += a[i][j]
            rec(i + 1, False)
            for j in range(n):
                s[j] -= a[i][j]

    rec(0, True)
    return best_s


def main():
    s = search([
        [1, 3, 0],
        [2, 1, 4]
    ])
    print(s, cost(s))

    s = search([
        [0, 0, 5],
        [0, 4, 0],
        [0, 8, 0],
        [2, 1, 0],
        [3, 0, 0]
    ])
    print(s, cost(s))


main()
```

> ```
> $ python temp.py
> [3, 4, 4] (1, -11)
> [5, 5, 5] (0, -15)
> ```